customize Generic repository
I have a big problem, suppose we have a app that has 50 tables and for the Crud operation, 50 Repositories must be written. To solve this problem, I use Generic Repository, but most of the tables have a special Customize series.  For example, when inserting in a table, duplicate data should not be added, and in a table, adding duplicate data is not important!  In your opinion, what scenario and method should I choose to get the best result and also the best performance?
        private readonly ApplicationContext context;  
        private DbSet < T > entities;  
        string errorMessage = string.Empty;  
        public Repository(ApplicationContext context) {  
            this.context = context;  
            entities = context.Set < T > ();  
        }  
        public IEnumerable < T > GetAll() {  
            return entities.AsEnumerable();  
        }  
        public T Get(long id) {  
            return entities.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == id);  
        }  
        public void Insert(T entity) {  
            if (entity == null) {  
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");  
            }  
            entities.Add(entity);  
            context.SaveChanges();  
        }  
        public void Update(T entity) {  
            if (entity == null) {  
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");  
            }  
            context.SaveChanges();  
        }  
        public void Delete(T entity) {  
            if (entity == null) {  
                throw new ArgumentNullException("entity");  
            }  
            entities.Remove(entity);  
            context.SaveChanges();  
        }  
       


Duplicate data should be handled by constraints on the database (unique indexes), not in code.  Also, your repository code is very inflexible, saving changes after every insert, update, or delete can be very slow.  Much better to only save after ALL changes have been made.

Use [EF Core indexes]https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/indexes?tabs=data-annotations) to handle duplicate data, not code

Also, in EF Core the DbContext is a repository already. Wrapping it in yet another repository is not recommended.
